# What is function of this circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

Here is my task (digital electronics)

For circuit below find:

a) In which logic it operates and what is function of this circuit;

b) Max. number of outputs, if circuit is part of chain of same circuits. Observe low voltage level.

It is known: Vcc=5V, R=4k, R1=2.5k, R2=1.6k, R3=130, R4=1k, VCE_saturation=0.2V, VBE_saturation=0.75V, VBE=0.7V, VD=0.7V, beta=20.

[image]

If it is TTL, BJT can be in cutoff, saturation or inverse active mode. But there are 8 BJTs, how can I know in which mode they work? It would be quite impossible to test every combination of BJT modes.

Comment: Would it? Hint: break it into stages. T1 and T3 work identically to T2 and T4. How do they combine to drive T5? T6 can be in only one of two states; this determines the states of T7 and T8. There are only a few *unique* combinations that you actually need to consider.

Comment: Question a) implies that you would analyze this as a logic element. So one way would be to set the input A and B to each of the 4 combinations of 0 and Vcc then work from left to right for each of the combinations.

Comment: I think what it does is whichever input is applied first automatically overrides the other input, but passing the first.  Would work great on perhaps ...Family Feud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exclusive Or circuit.  Either input, but not both.

Comment: *BZZT!* Wrong. But thanks for playing. Seriously, with homework questions like this, we don't just blurt out the solution. We try to guide the OP toward discovering the answer on his own ... assuming he shows any interest in doing so.

Comment: I thought this was like a game show.  Man.